# Fazer uma busca independente da ordem das palavras chave

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma base de dados no qual preciso fazer uma busca baseando nas palavras chaves, independente da ordem. Vejam a tabela completa abaixo:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |     description       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | joão de santo cristo  |
| 2  | eduardo e mô nica     |
| 3  | santo cristo joão     |
| 4  | cristo santo joão     |
| 5  | juazeiro do norte     |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Quando faço um busca com a usando `LIKE "%joão%cristo%"` o resultado é:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |     description       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | joão de santo cristo  |
+----+-----------------------+
```

A *query* busca somente resultado de acordo com a ordem das palavras, primeiro `joão` acompanhando de qualquer coisa e segundo `cristo`. Gostaria que o retorno fosse desta forma abaixo independente da ordem das palavras. Vejam:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |     description       |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | joão de santo cristo  |
| 2  | santo cristo joão     |
| 3  | cristo santo joão     |
+----+-----------------------+
```

Como seria a *query* para fazer uma busca na base de dados independente da ordem das palavras?

Comment: Creio que isto resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873328/sql-search-for-words-in-any-order

Comment: @Miguel dei uma olhada no link, mas não está resolvendo o problema. A resposta lá pareceu uma abordagem legal, mas no meu caso aqui não está retornando como desejado. Vou fazer mais algumas pesquisas aqui.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Mude o motor da tabela de MyISAM (que é o padrão), para InnoDB.

2) Adicione um índice do tipo `FULLTEXT` no campo que terá a procura.

```
ALTER TABLE `nometabela` ADD FULLTEXT `idx_fulltext_nomecoluna` (`nomecoluna`);
```

3) Utilize a *query* com `MATCH` ... `AGAINST` da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT * FROM nomedatabela WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST('joão cristo');
```

Fiz um teste para revisar se era isso mesmo a receita de bolo e é isso mesmo. Segue um print do teste:
[image: Query com match against]

Para retornar apenas registros que tiver as duas palavras juntas, basta adicionar o `IN BOOLEAN MODE` ao método `AGAINST` com o operador `+` em cada palavra chave. Veja abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM nomedatabela WHERE MATCH(description) 
AGAINST('+joão +cristo' in boolean mode);
```

Para saber mais sobre a representação de cada operador, veja mais detalhes na documentação sobre [Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Como assim mudar a "coluna description para full text"? Tem como detalhar melhor sua resposta? Eu tentei fazer desta forma, mas não funciona comigo.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja agora.

Comment: Fiz uma adaptação e funcionou beleza. Desta forma que você está fazendo, vai retornar qualquer registro que tiver uma das duas palavras ou as duas juntos independente da posição que elas encontram. No meu caso eu precisava retornar somente os registros que tiver as duas palavras chave juntas. Então acrescentei  o "`IN BOOLEAN MODE`" e o operador `+` em cada palavra chave.  Talvez eu não tenha deixado explicito, mas é o que queria passar. Se quiser adaptar, eu valido sua resposta. Enfim, obrigado!

Comment: Beleza, adicionei o in boolean mode com os sinais de +. :)

Comment: Alterei a resposta, deixando o que você tinha feito e acrescentando a adaptação e também um link de referência. Obrigado mais uma vez. Abraços.

Comment: Me ajudou também porque eu ainda não conhecia o 'in boolean mode'. Valew! Grande abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

```
description LIKE "%joão%cristo%" OR description LIKE "%cristo%joão%"
```

Essa segunda condição `%cristo%joão%` lhe fornecerá as linhas que faltam na consulta:

- santo cristo joão
- cristo santo joão

Comment: Parcialmente pode até resolver, mas não considero isso muito eficaz considerando que haver não somente duas palavras, mas sim, por exemplo 10 palavras chaves. Qual seria sua estratégia quanto a isso?

Answer (score 0):

algo assim , montando um sql dinamico

com base em um array com as palavras

joao
santo
cristo

```
select * 
from tabela
where (
       description like '%joao%'
       or
       description like '%santo%'
       or
       description like '%cristo%'
      )
order by (sign(instr(description ,'joao')) +
          sign(instr(description ,'santo')) +
          sign(instr(description ,'cristo')))
```

leia também sobre
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html